# How do i resolve this AttributeError?

Tags: python

```
File "/home/mark/cmsPoc/scripts/beecms/v40_fileupload_getshell.py", line 38, in poc
path = re.search(p,r.text).group(0)
```

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: What is p, what is r ? How could we help if don't know what you're doing

Comment: I could not paste all the code here

Answer (score 2):

The error appears because `re.search` returns `None` when not matching anything.

In order to fix the error, check whether `re.search(p, r.text) is None` before trying to access `group(0)` or fix your regex if not matching anything is unexpected behavior.